# Are libraries built using the Linux subsystem in Windows 10 accessible to a Windows development environment?

Tags: dll, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I'm currently trying to connect MongoDB to a Windows QT C++ application and am following the tutorial [here](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html). While there Windows installation instructions are presented, to avoid having to install Visual Studio or other tools, I'm wondering if I can follow the package-manager or Linux instructions on the inbuilt Linux/ Ubuntu subsystem of Windows 10 and build the libraries in my Linux environment, later somehow accessing them from my Windows development environment.

I don't fully understand how compilation/ byte-code works in the Linux subsystem on Windows, so I haven't been able to piece together an answer for this myself based on my understanding of the various systems involved. Any explanation or assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a Windows executable from a WSL console window or a Linux executable from Windows command line / power shell. And capture the output, pipe between applications etc. But the application must run entirely on one platform; you cannot mix a Windows executable with Linux libraries or vice-versa.

I don't know how you will connect to MongoDB but, if it has a socket interface like MySql, you could create a bash script on WSL which runs your QT application to access the database, wherever it is.

But if you're using QT as a GUI you're going to struggle. People have been able to get a Linux desktop running on WSL by installing an X server on the Windows host but you might find that more trouble than it's worth.